# How to do colored 2D grid with 3 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, colors, grid

I have three arrays of equal length x, y, and z. The x and y arrays are the x-axis and y-axis for the grid. The z array will determine the color of the the grid block. For example,

```
x = [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30]
y = [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]
z = [100, 54, 32, 67, 71, 88, 100, 15, 29]
```

It is easy to make 3D plots out of this like

```
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap=cm.RdYlGn)
```

or

```
ax.bar3d(x, y, [0] * len(x), 100, 100, z, cmap=cm.RdYlGn)
```

But I am looking for something like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiQiG.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you have tried?

Comment: Also, it helps to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.meshgrid` returns a tuple of two 2D arrays, which you can unpack directly

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

However, you don't need to those for an imshow plot. What you need and what you lack in your code is the 2D array of `z` values. This would be the array to provide to `imshow`.

```
img = plt.imshow(Z)
```

If you want to use meshgrid instead, you can use your `X` and `Y` values,

```
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
```

Seeing the example data, you can use imshow:

```
x = [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30]
y = [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]
z = [100, 54, 32, 67, 71, 88, 100, 15, 29]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

z = np.array(z).reshape(3,3)

plt.imshow(z,extent=[5,35,5,35])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: so am I suppose to use X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) then plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)? Seems simple enough but it doesn't work.

Comment: You may of course update your question with a [mcve] of the issue and a problem description which tells more than just 'it doesn't work'. Otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: No problem. I added a picture that illustrates what I'm looking for.

Comment: in this case you can easily use `imshow`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the way my array is z generated, it doesn't come out in order. However the index of x, y, z is correlated together. I will just post a new question with more details but thanks for the help!